Spamassassin: increase spam score for emoticons in email subject line
We are receiving more and more spam messages and marketing mails with emoticons in the subject line and I want to increase the spam score of such messages using a custom spam assassin rule.
It seems the emoticons are not embedded images, but technically normal UTF-8 characters, since they even show up when loading of images from email messages in disabled in the email client. There seems to be no way to remove/block them in Outlook or Thunderbird.
My questions are:

Can you confirm that these emoticons are UTF-8 characters, or suggest how I could test that?

I would like to create a custom spam assassin rule to increase the spam score of messages that contain these emoticons in the subject line. How would I do this? If the are UTF-8 characters, is there a character range of emoticons I could look for?


Example image of messages:

I don't think this is a good idea. While personally I'm not a fan of emojis, especially in official communications, it's pretty common nowadays even for reputable companies to use them. I don't think its helpful to use it as an indicator for spam.

Just searching for uft8 range emojis with your favourite search engine should show results like this.

Thanks for our comments! So the answer to the first question is 'yes', it seems. Regarding bad idea: I agree in general, and your comment is justified and may be valuable for others reading this. I myself would not do this if I was the mail admin of a large organization. But our mail server is for a group of 5 people who agree they dislike the emoticons enough to take action against them. And we do currently not get emails from reputable organizations with emoticons in them (except for marketing messages, which we are fine flagging as spam). Of course, this may change in the future.

So apparently the are UTF-8, and spread all over the place according to that link. It seems email got even more annoying. To be clear: I am not against emoji in the message body. But if they are in the subject line, I cannot visually search my inbox for a certain message anymore, because my eyes always get drawn to the ones with images. They are like a magnet. It's horrible.

Maybe you're right and spam assassin is the wrong tool for this problem. Maybe people should just delete all these emails individually, or put them into a separate folder so they do not annoy them. If it keeps annoying me enough, I will look into automating it on the user level via procmail. @GeraldSchneider Would you mind officially answering this question, instead of writing a comment?
